# Read commands from text file and run it in Qshell

Tags: shell, unix, ibm-midrange

I have a file which has commands written in lines. I need to read the file and run the commands written in it in QSHELL. I know we can do it with :
`ls < test.txt` but could not get any documentation for < command. Please let me know if there is some other better way to do it .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [**qsh**](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzahz/rzahzqsh.htm) utility accepts a *command file* as a parameter and runs the commands contained in the file.

```
qsh test.txt
```

---

`<` is a standard [redirection](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzahz/rzahzredirect.htm) operator.

---

The [**ls**](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzahz/rzahzls.htm)  utility does not process stdin so the example to list specific files would not work the way you expect.

The [**xargs**](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzahz/rzahzxargs.htm) utility will execute a specified command (utility) with parameters from stdin.

```
xargs ls < test.txt
```

Assuming **test.txt** contains the following lines:

<kbd>a</kbd>
<kbd>b</kbd>
<kbd>c</kbd>

It would execute the following command:

```
ls a b c
```

You can limit the number of parameters with the **-n** parameter.

```
xargs -n 1 ls < test.txt
```

This would execute the following individual commands:

```
ls a
ls b
ls c
```